# Cabal: Odd Error Message + Lack of Documentation

Tags: haskell, cabal

So I recently installed cabal (from the default binary of ArchLinux).
I then tried to upgrade cabal as a user:

> cabal upgrade Cabal --user --prefix=$USER
>   Resolving dependencies...
>   cabal: fromFlag NoFlag. Use fromFlagOrDefault

What I've already done:

1. Googled the error message. Turned up the cabal source and little else.
2. Looked at haskell-wiki on cabal-install.
3. Looked through [this guide.](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/Cabal/index.html)

So basically I'm wondering:

- What's up with the error message?
- Could anyone point me in the direction of a cabal tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a bug in Arch's package. I'm running Arch as well, and I got the same error.

I then built cabal-install (0.8.2) from Hackage, which didn't complain when I run `cabal upgrade Cabal`. In fact, it started building right away, although I didn't let it finish because I didn't feel comfortable upgrading a core package.

May I ask why you wanted to upgrade Cabal? The version that comes with ghc is 1.8.0.2, and the latest version is 1.8.0.4 -- not too distant IMO. Besides, if you're running cabal-install as normal user, why not simply `cabal install`? It doesn't have permission to overwrite the system files anyway.

Comment: Solved! Apparently it was just the permissions that where off *smacks forehead*. I had no particular reason to upgrade cabal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing wildly here, but can you see if

- You have a nonstandard `Setup.hs`?
- You have `flags:` set in `~/.cabal/config`?

The most helpful tutorial I have found is not ostensibly about Cabal; it is called [*How to Write a Haskell Program*](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program).

I have looked through the guide you mention (the official Cabal documentation), and the information I wanted is a tiny bit of flotsam swimming in a sea of complexity.  I assume that the complexity serves some useful purpose, since I know that good people have been working very hard on Cabal for several years, but as an outsider, I find the state of play discouraging.  I was just barely able to build, install, and upload a simple package of my own—with a little help from my friends on SO.

I tentatively suggest you might want to avoid `cabal upgrade` and maybe try `cabal install` instead, and see if you can move forward with your original goals.

Answer (score 0):

From [user tlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306877/tlo):

> The global configuration file for cabal-install is ~/.cabal/config. If
>   you do not have this file, cabal will create it for you on the first
>   call to cabal update.

I deleted my config, ran `cabal update`, and all was good.